# Centering an image and resize it from center. Without margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place a heart image in the center of the user's screen. And every time I click it should be resized and grown .

The main problem is that i want to do that with no margin.
Can you help me please?

Edit 1 -
This is my code so far, but it is really messy and uses margin

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<style>
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#Msg1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
 display:none;
 position:absolute;

  margin-right:55%;
  margin-top: 45%;
}
body {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#ffd6d6;
}

</style>
<script>
var size=100;
var i=0;
var heartImage = document.getElementById('container');
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(function() {
  $("#Msg1").fadeIn("slow");
  });
 $(function() {
    $("#container")
        .mouseover(function() { 
        if(i==0){
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.png";
            $(this).animation
            $(this).attr("src", src);}
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("over.png", ".png");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        });
});
  $("#container").click(function(){
  i++;
  if(i==1)
  {
  $("#Msg1").fadeOut("fast");
  }
  if(i==6)
  {
  $("body").css("background-color","#9d1b1b");
   $("#container").hide();
  }
  size=size*2;
   $("#container").animate({
      height:size,
      width:size,
      margin:-size/2,  
    });
  });

});

</script>
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
<img id="container" src="heart.png" alt="null"/>
<div  id="Msg1">
</div>

</body>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cbj4m/) is the code in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Have you got any code so far? If so add it to the question.

Comment: Would there be a jsfiddle or something of your attempt to do this? Can't you just simply absolutely position it in the center with css/js and increase width and height?

Comment: do you previously know the height of the content?

Comment: [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform) && [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin) might be useful...

Comment: @Sanchit I can position the image in the center of the screen but I use margin

Comment: @Teemu I need an animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple code that doesn't uses `margins` it uses `display:table` , `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`, the problem with this solution is that you need to know the height of the view (you can always get it via JavaScript/jQuery but I fixed it in 400px just for the example).

[Here is the jsFiddle with the working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/JMxfT/)

This is the simple HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="heart"></div> 
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

The jQuery 'click' bind: (it toggles the event now, just for showing purpose)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".heart").click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("bigger");
    })
});
```

And the CSS (I use the CSS3 transition here (with the vendor prefixes) but you can animate it via jQuery to make ir cross-browser

```
body{
    height:400px;
}
.content{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
}
.inner{
    text-align:center
}
.heart{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;

    display:inline-block;
    background: transparent url('http://wbom.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/red-heart.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 250px;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}
.bigger{
     background-size: 350px;
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
}
```

Hope it helps, sorry if it is too long.
Cheers.